# How long does it take to send a postcard from Germany to China

Tags: germany, china, mail

I sent a postcard **2 weeks** ago from Germany to Beijing. I bought `2 x 0.45€`stamps, and put it in a Deutsche Post box.

Is there any way to know how long does it take for the postcard to arrive the destination? I couldn't find any information online.

Comment: For German travellers, it is well known that sending postcards from their vacation to home takes between 3 days and several months (although mostly several weeks). So for sending it to China I wouldn't be surprised to see a month or more. There is no guaranteed duration.

Comment: @Kuba I am asking specifically `Germany-China` mail. How is it related to that question?

Comment: Because the first answer exactly answers your question https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/95733/41551
"Sometimes you can get a letter from the other end of the world in 1 week and sometimes it takes 40 days to get a postcard from a neighboring country. "

Comment: I have several hundred postcads from all around the world, and for example between Poland and Russia (even bigger cities) and it took them 2 weeks - 18 months (!) to arrive

Comment: @Kuba Yes, but what I want to know is, if there exist a **written rule** regarding postcards or not.

Comment: Provided that you are near a Post Box and have all the required items and data, I would say like you need 1 minute to **send** the postcard(write the address, fix the stamp and drop the postcard in the box). It may need some time more to **arrive** to its destination, though... :-D

Comment: @Kuba 18 months?! I'll just walk there

Comment: @JohnSmith haha I think it got lost in transit and later recovered, usually from Russia it takes 2 weeks - 2 months. On Postcrossing forum a lot of people complain about Russian post...

Comment: From my personal postcrossing stats (Germany->China): 18 postcards, minimum time 11 days, maximum 160 days (avg. 36 days). Sure, rural China might be different than Beijing, but only 4 out of 18 arrived within two weeks, so relax.

Comment: @Sabine Thank you, I hope mine takes two to three weeks as well. I am relaxed, I wasn't freaking out :)

Comment: Do they go through Russia?  A friend of mine told me of being on a train in Russia and watching to men in uniform pulling mail out of a mail bag, opening letters, laughing at what they read, and throwing them out the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The online postage calculator of *Deutsche Post* [states](https://www.portokalkulator.de/portokalkulator/std?calculator=int.brief&country=CHN&shiptype=karte&count=1&weight=14%2C7%20g&length=23%2C5%20cm&width=12%2C5%20cm&height=0%20mm&pre_weight=14%2C7%20g&pre_calculator=int.postkarte&pre_width=12%2C5%20cm&pre_length=23%2C5%20cm&pre_country=CHN&pre_shiptype=karte&pre_height=0%20mm&pre_count=1&pre_pkcformula=int.postkarte) that letters sent as *Standardbrief International* usually take 6 to 14 working days to reach China. That's about one to three weeks in absolute time.

However, no suche assertion is made about the *Postkarte International* product. I know that postcards in general have a very low priority with mail carriers, so despite both products costing 90 cents, I would not be surprised if you would have to double that number to get the expected transit time for a Postkarte.

Next time, you could put the card into an envelope and send it as letter, if you want to feel more confident about the transit time.

PS: *DHL* and *Deutsche Post* are technically different companies, so I really hope you did not use one of the DHL parcel drops, but a true DP letter box. All those Post spin-offs become quite iffy when they are confused for one another (my favorite being that DHL support does know nothing about DHL Express packages, because they're different companies -.-)

Comment: Now that I think about it, it might have been Deutsche Post :D

Comment: @John Yes, probably. Parcel drops are uncommon, and do not look like letter boxes. :) There's also big, automated package lockers, but they look even less like a postbox. Regular DP letter boxes are quite common and easily recognizable. They only feature the post horn, tho, so you might not even have read the company name.